# Is it okay to copy a WAR file and paste it to another location while it is still deployed and running by Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

For a Java web application. I have a need to get a copy of the WAR file and examine its code. However I do not want to bring the application down as it is currently deployed by Tomcat. If I simply copy the deployed WAR file and paste it in some other folder in Windows File Explorer, this operation would not affect the current application correct? Or do I need to actually bring down the application and let our users know we need a downtime before I do a copy and paste operation of the WAR file?

Comment: You can copy it without any problem.

Comment: It's just a file; unless the app is doing something *incredibly* weird like reaching into the file and rewriting it on-the-fly, no (and even then it *could* still be okay depending).

Comment: What is your O/S?  Windows sometimes has a file locking issue doing this, depending on your O/S, Tomcat, and Java version.

Comment: @stdunbar The OS is windows. If there is a locking issue, it should at most prevent me from copying right? And that is fine. I just don't want it to break the current running application. If that makes sense.

Comment: That is correct @photonacl - worst case it stops you.  But if it doesn't stop you then you should be fine.

Comment: @stdunbar That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have issues with that.